# How to catch the Fn+? keys on laptop?

Tags: delphi

Can I catch the Fn+F3( or Fn+F2....) keys with my program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Leo, the main function of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> is change the [scancodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode) of other keys on the keyboard, unfortunately the Fn key ***usually*** (in some systems this key returns an ScanCode) doesn't have an scan code, additionally the behavior of this key is not standardized as other keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>) because of this is very hard detect or intercept when this key is pressed.

You can check theses links for more info

- [Mystery of the Fn key - A guide to remapping the Fn key in Windows](http://www.autohotkey.net/~daonlyfreez/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm)
- [Keyboard scancodes](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=VS.85).aspx) is the list of keycodes from MSDN. Using the information there, you could probably figure out which key codes to listen for.

As @RRUZ mentioned above, the `FN` key *modifies* the key code being sent.

You could always create a `MessageBox` that displays the key code whenever you press a key and use the values it gives you.

Comment: Yes, "Left" arrow key scancode is 37, "Fn+Left" scancode is 36, while "J" scancode is 74, but "Fn+J" scancode is still 74

Comment: @diyism: That probably means that "Fn+J" is not a valid modifier.