# RegisterHotkey Fn Modifier?

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, pinvoke, hotkeys

I know you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, etc. modifiers for RegisterHotKey, but what about the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key?

I used to have some bloatware on my laptop that changed brightness when Fn+Up/Down was pressed.  I removed all the bloatware, and I want to write a program that does the same thing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777796/how-to-catch-the-fn-keys-on-laptop

Comment: The Virtual Keycodes don't include anything for Fn keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> key is modifier but not software like <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, etc. which are processed by operation system. <kbd>Fn</kbd> is hardware key modifier so it changes keycode keyboard sends to operation system.

For example <kbd>←</kbd> is 37 and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> is 36 so when you need to handle <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> press you need to react on 36 keycode.

**PS.** On some keyboards Fn key send keycode so it can be handled seperatly, but usualy they don't.