# How to turn on 3G?

Tags: windows, mobile, 3g

I've got a recent problem. I've got several notebooks with 3G modules in them (notebook manufacturer).
When I restart one, it always recovers the last state of the connections. If WLAN/Bluetooth has been switched on the last time, it also starts switched on. Turning them off and restart the notebook then, they remain off.

But the 3G doesnt follow this pattern. It always is turned off after a restart.
Some of our customers use this connection permanently, so they're looking for a solution that keeps 3G on when launching.
Apparently, I don't have one. :)

It doesn't matter how this will be solved: C#, VBS, CMD/Batch, RegHacks, ...
I'm open to every idea. :)

Ideas that has been tried:

- [Simulating <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>any</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571152/how-to-simulate-a-fn-keypress-for-notebooks-or-how-to-switch-on-3g)
- Using DevCon with hardware-IDs (partial functional, but unavailable at restart)

Targeted OS:

- Windows 7
- Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds as though you want to turn the 3G device's radio on.  You can do this in C# or C++ via Windows Mobile Broadband [IMbnRadio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IMbnRadioEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces.

I had a quick look on Google for a Windows setting that would tell the OS not to deactivate the device at shutdown, but didn't find anything.

EDIT:
MbnApi does let you do a lot of things.  It consists of many interfaces, and the two that I linked to above are specifically for switching the radio off and on.  You don't need the rest.

The 3G module can either be software disabled (radio off/on) or hardware disabled (a switch on the computer).  The exact implementation of these two things, is up to the individual manufacturer.  They don't work exactly the same on machines from different manufacturers.
 Some computers just switch off the 3G radio and the device stays powered up, others power the device down completely.

Comment: Your answer looks like a solution. I'm expected to be at work at Tuesday (currently sick, urgh), where I can test it. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Get well soon!  If you're going to use C# by the way, there is a white paper linked on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323271(v=vs.85).aspx about using the MBN APIs.  The same interfaces are valid in Windows 8 Desktop.

Comment: Hey pal! I'm now over your solution. It's a bit quirky, but I'm advancing. I added "MbnApi" to y project and can work with it. But I'm not sure, if that really is the solution I'm looking for. I really just need to turn the 3G Module on/off. With your class it seems like everything is possible (like sending and receiving SMS), but not switching it on/off. Or am I just blind?

Comment: Oh shizzle, maybe I explained it wrong: I dont want to connect the *3G connection* with anything. I just want to switch on/off the *UMTS device*! Have been experimenting now and I guess we're on the wrong trail...

Comment: Ok, I have now used [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097000/how-do-i-disable-a-system-device-programatically) to switch the device's state. It works! And I'm glad of that. But as i want to simulate Fn+?, it won't work. The Fn works like "de-power" it. Pressing it again will turn it on again. The hardware-ID remains the same, even powered or unpowered. Is there a way to switch the power state of it?

Comment: @Trollwut see the text that I added above.  Why does your solution not work?  Does it not power the device on?

Comment: Yessir, that's my problem... with your API I managed to switch off the RADIO (did I miss something?), but our notebooks (we got two manufacturers and are resellers) power off the whole device. My problem now is, that customers are end-customers. So when they switch it off per API (radio off) and want to turn it on again with Fn+?, then it's radio-off and device-off. After reenabling, it's device-on but radio-off. We cannot assure, that customers will use both methods seperately, therefore I need to switch device off.

Comment: Nasty.  Can you go back to the manufacturer, and ask them what they recommend?  Can they give you a way to stop the computer from disabling the device at re-start?

Comment: If a modem port is visible, it might be possible to use AT commands to enable/disable the device.  The disadvantage is the AT commands are proprietary, and different for each device manufacturer.  It isn't always clear which AT commands correspond to which power state, for example some manufacturers offer more than just the two options radio off and power off.  I just mention them for completeness.

Comment: I asked for some pattern, code, tip or anything for my problem. The first answer was, that an enabled UMTS is a must because of airline companies. I haven't found anything for that on the interwebs (except that ALL connections have to be turned off during start and landing - but in-flight, they don't matter). I answered them, that this isn't the answer I expected, etc. I didn't get a response since then... seems like they don't know the solution, too. :D You have to see, that I only have contact to sales man. I don't think that they even know the programmers...

Comment: Try a very focussed question like "How can I stop the computer from disabling the device at startup (or shutdown)?"  In my experience, it's harder for them to escape from specific questions.  Or maybe ask them for a technical contact.  Communication is often the worst technical problem to solve :-(  Are you in Germany? (guessing from your name)  If yes, then I'm not aware of any requirements for automatically switching the radio off.  Most mfrs don't do it.

Comment: So I have to try again... Jawohl, ich bin Deutscher! Nope, I'm also not aware of such treatments in Germany and as Google has been my lawyer, there is none. I haven't found ANY evidence for that rumor. Well ok, I really appreaciate your help! Is therea way to thank you on this site without you having posted a solution? (cu tomorrow)

Comment: Nichts zu danken, bis morgen!

Comment: Ok, I'm abandoning this project. As I'm leaving the company this week, there is no time left. It's not a big deal, but a bummer that I haven't got it. If there is any another solution, please share it to tell others who will encounter that problem. :) Thanks, @S List, for your patience and help!